# To get user details from Chat of MS BoT Framework

Tags: botframework

We want to build a BoT and want to target 3 channels Webchat, Teams and Email. For these channels can we capture the logged in user.

Don’t think we can do in Web Chat channel.

In teams -- can we capture the email id of the logged in user chatting with BoT?
in email channel -- can we capture the sender email id who has emailed to our BoT?

any sample code?

Answer (score 0):

The IDs are included in the JSON sent to your bot when it receives a message (see "From").  Here is an example (from an email received by a bot):

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "id": "AAMkAD....",
  "timestamp": "2017-01-09T21:18:06.113698Z",
  "serviceUrl": "https://email.azurewebsites.net/",
  "channelId": "email",
  "from": {
    "id": "**EMAIL HERE**",
    "name": "**USER NAME HERE**"
  },
```